# How to make a container that fill the remaining screen height and is scrollable?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm trying to make a fixed div that it's a container and i want to make only this container be scrollable, the rest of the page I want to be fixed.
Here is what I have: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7cjtgp?file=src%2FApp.js).
Here's a component called "PageDefault" that has the Header and involves each page in application(the content of the page is the prop "children" inside PageDefault's component).

Here is what I would like to do:
[image]

Minimal Example of what I have(without react):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .header {
        top: 0px;
        background-color: green;
        height: 100px;
      }

      .page-title {
        height: 300px;
        background-color: blue;
      }

      .content {
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">header goes here</div>
    <div class="page-title">page title goes here</div>

    <div class="content">
      blablabla blablabla blabla bla blabla blablabla bla blabla bla blablabla
      blabla bla blabla blablabla blabla bla blabla bla bla blablabla blablabla
      blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blablabla blablabla blabla bla
      blabla blablabla bla blabla bla blablabla blabla bla blabla blablabla
      blabla bla blabla bla bla blablabla blablabla blabla bla blabla bla blabla
      bla blabla bla blablabla blablabla blabla bla blabla blablabla bla blabla
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Linking to your code offset is generally not considered acceptable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) -- please instead include a [mcve] of your code in the question body (preferably as a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry! I've just updated with a minimal example(without react but with the same result) and a example on stackblitz(with react)

Answer (score 4):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.wrap {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  background: orange;
  padding: 1em;
}

h1 {
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  background: pink;
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <header>HEADER</header>
  <h1>TITLE</h1>
  <main>
    <p></p>
  </main>
</div>
```